# How to modify xml file without encoding special characters

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization

I have the following XML sample to serialize and deserialize:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Students>
  <Student ID="1">
    <Name>sss</Name>
  </Student>
  <Student ID="2">
    <Name>&quot;</Name>
  </Student>
  <Student ID="3">
    <Name>Test3 </Name>
  </Student>
</Students>
```

When i try to deserialize the xml i get **& quot ;** as " 
I need to deal with this special character and other special characters as it is without any change in deserializing the document and serializing it after some modifications.

I have tried all XML manipulation techniques like Linq to XML, XMLDocument and XMLText but the same result.

Is there any way to handle this issue even if with a work a round?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The problem here seems to be that you want to work with both the data and its stored representation at the same time. The underlying *data* here is a quote character. The *xml representation* of that is `&quot;`. So as soon as you load your xml using a deserializer, you lose the information about *storage*, and can see only the *data*. You need to decide if you want to manipulate the *xml itself* as text (in which case, work directly on the text), or you want to modify the data stored in the xml (in which case, deserialize, and work on that data). Why exactly are you trying to do both at once?

Comment: Or escape the & => &amp;quot;